# How can I get object instance from ()=>foo.Title expression

Tags: c#, data-binding, .net-3.5, expression-trees, lambda

I have a simple class with a property

```
class Foo 
{ 
    string Title { get; set; } 
}
```

I am trying to simplify data binding by calling a function like

```
BindToText(titleTextBox, ()=>foo.Title );
```

which is declared like

```
void BindToText<T>(Control control, Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    var mex = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    string name = mex.Member.Name;

    control.DataBindings.Add("Text", ??? , name);
}
```

so what do I put in `???` for the instance of my `Foo` class. How do I get a refernce to the calling `foo` instance from the lambda expression?

**edit:**
The instance should be there somewhere because I can call `property.Compile()` and create a delegate that uses the `foo` instance inside my `BindToText` function. So my question is if this can be done without adding a reference to the instance in the function parameters. I call upon [Occum's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) to yield the simplest solution.

**edit 2:**
What many have failed to notice is the *closure* that exists in accessing the instance of `foo` inside my function, if I compile the lambda. How come the compiler knows where to find the instance, and I don't? I insist that there has to be an answer, *without* having to pass an extra argument.

---

### Solution

Thanks to [VirtualBlackFox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46594/virtualblackfox) the solution is such:

```
void BindText<T>(TextBoxBase text, Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    var mex = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    string name = mex.Member.Name;
    var fex = mex.Expression as MemberExpression;
    var cex = fex.Expression as ConstantExpression;            
    var fld = fex.Member as FieldInfo;
    var x = fld.GetValue(cex.Value);
    text.DataBindings.Add("Text", x, name);            
}
```

which alows me to simply type `BindText(titleText, () => foo.Title);`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Small [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) sample of what you want :

```
void Foo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> prop)
{
    var propertyGetExpression = prop.Body as MemberExpression;

    // Display the property you are accessing, here "Height"
    propertyGetExpression.Member.Name.Dump();

    // "s" is replaced by a field access on a compiler-generated class from the closure
    var fieldOnClosureExpression = propertyGetExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;

    // Find the compiler-generated class
    var closureClassExpression = fieldOnClosureExpression.Expression as ConstantExpression;
    var closureClassInstance = closureClassExpression.Value;

    // Find the field value, in this case it's a reference to the "s" variable
    var closureFieldInfo = fieldOnClosureExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
    var closureFieldValue = closureFieldInfo.GetValue(closureClassInstance);

    closureFieldValue.Dump();

    // We know that the Expression is a property access so we get the PropertyInfo instance
    // And even access the value (yes compiling the expression would have been simpler :D)
    var propertyInfo = propertyGetExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(closureFieldValue, null);
    propertyValue.Dump();
}

void Main()
{
    string s = "Hello world";
    Foo(() => s.Length);
}
```

Comment: Some magic LINQPad method, I guess. You can probably just return or print that instead.

Comment: +1 for getting me closer. Alas, `constantInstanceExpression.Value` returns the instance of the form, not the field `foo` in the form. What if there are several classes inside the form that are used for Bindings? I don't want to statically bind to `foo`, but to whatever is used in the Property.

Comment: Added everything in the sample that you could want :D Even interpreting the expression manually to get the field value :D

Comment: [v/] Thats it!. Now I have a simple way to do DataBinding... awesome

Answer (score 4):

Don't. Just modify the method to take another parameter, as described in [#3444294](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444294). For your example, it may be something like this:

```
void BindToText<T>(Control control, T dataSource, Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    var mex = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    string name = mex.Member.Name;

    control.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSource, name);
}
```

and would be called like

```
BindToText(titleTextBox, foo, ()=>foo.Title );
```

Still nice, but easy to understand. There's no magic happening. ;)

Comment: Thanks but I want to avoid doing so. Look at my edit above, and see that there should be a way to get to it, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
void BindToText<T>(Control control, Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    var mex = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    string name = mex.Member.Name;

    var fooMember = mex.Expression as MemberExpression;
    var fooConstant = fooMember.Expression as ConstantExpression;
    var foo = fooConstant.Value;

    control.DataBindings.Add("Text", foo, name);
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ooops, just realized that this is, more or less, the same answer as VisualBlackFox's...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is similar in tone to Hangy's solution, but is I think rather comfortable to use and does not require much magic:

```
public static Binding CreateTextBinding<T>(this T source, Expression<Func<T,object>> access)
{
    var mex = access.Body as MemberExpression;
    string name = mex.Member.Name;
    return new Binding("Text", source, name);
}
```

This is basically an extension method that can be called on any object acting as source. It gives you back a Binding for a Text property which you can add to any Bindings collection.