# Don't understand compile error for method call with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092387/how-can-i-get-object-instance-from-foo-title-expression) to "pass a property as a parameter to a method" and change the property's value with an additional parameter. My problem is not how to accomplish that but rather the method call results in a compile error.

**Call and method definition**

```
Run(f => f.A, 15);

public static void Run<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> lamdaExpression, TValue value)
```

I get this error:

> Error CS0411: The type arguments for method `Program.Run<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>>, TValue)` cannot be inferred from
>   the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

I have already searched on the above message and there are several examples, none are like mine. So I don't understand what is the problem.
Please help!

**Additional information**
I have one similar method call and method definition which don't have this problem. So I'm a bit confused.

```
Run(foo, f => f.A, 10);

public static void Run<T, TValue>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> property, TValue value)
```

Notice this method has the same `Expression<Func<T, TValue>> property` and its working.

The program I've been using:

```
class Foo
{
    public int A {get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         var foo = new Foo();

         //... Calls to the methods...
    }
}
```

Comment: The type of `T` can't be inferred from the lambda expression.
The second method works because the type of `T` is inferred from the first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `f => f.A` cannot be used to infer the type of `f`.

So, easy fix:

```
Run<Foo, int>(f => f.A, 15);
```

Notice that if you have to specify one of the type arguments, you need to specify all of them.

Your other method works because `T` is inferred from the first parameter `T obj`