# How to create lambda expressions for every property of a class

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, expression

I have a following problem. I have to iterate over all the properties of the class to configure some builder. A class has a lot of properties, so the code is cumbersome. It looks like this:

```
var b = builder<MyTypeWith1000Properties>
    .WithProperty(x=>x.Property1)
    .WithProperty(x=>x.Property2)
    ...
    .WithProperty(x=>x.Property1000);
```

The code is repeated in many places for many differend types, not only MyTypeWith1000Properties. I was thinking about creating some extension, like this:

```
var b = builder<MyTypeWith1000Properties>
    .WithAllProperties();
```

and then in the WithAllProperties I could iterate over type properties using Reflection, like this:

```
public static IDataExtractor<T> WithAllProperties(this IDataExtractor<T> extractor)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        extractor = extractor.WithProperty(/*the problem is here/*);
    }
    return extractor;
}
```

How to convert the property variable in the loop to a corresponding expression

```
Expression<Func<TRow, TValue>> propertyExpression
```

as this is what WithProperty expects

Comment: Have a look at the `MemberExpression` class.

Comment: You seem to be going at the problem in a strange angle. What are you trying to do exactly ? I can't figure out why making that kind of filter which probably iterate exponentially.

Comment: I am trying to simplify code - imagine using this builder for different classes with a lot of properties (why there are so many properties is a different story). You need to copy-paste WithProperty many, many times and then change lambda to point at different property. I don't know what do you mean by "filtering" and why it would iterate exponentially.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5092387/380384

Comment: Is there anything special about `MyTypeWith100Properties` or is it just an ordinary class with fields and properties? Do you just care about properties?

Answer (score 0):

### Update - Setting the correct parameter value in Expression.Lambda>

You could try something like this

```
public static class BuilderExtension
{
    public static IDataExtractor<T> WithAllProperties<T>(this IDataExtractor<T> extractor)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property,parameter);
            extractor = extractor.WithProperty(lambda);
        }
        return extractor;
    }
}
```

Suppose you have the following class structures

```
public class MyTypeWith100Properties
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
}


public interface IDataExtractor<T>
{
    IDataExtractor<T> WithProperty(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr);
}

public class DataExtractor<T> : IDataExtractor<T>
{
    public List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> Expressions { get; private set; }

    public DataExtractor() {
        Expressions = new List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>();
    }
    public IDataExtractor<T> WithProperty(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        Expressions.Add(expr);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then if you run this

```
var builder = new DataExtractor<MyTypeWith100Properties>();
var b = builder.WithAllProperties<MyTypeWith100Properties>() 
                         as DataExtractor<MyTypeWith100Properties>;

var instance = new MyTypeWith100Properties() {
                        Property1 = "This is property 1",
                        Property2 = "This is property 2",
                        Property3 = "This is property 3",
                        Property4 = "This is property 4"
                    };

foreach (var current in b.Expressions)
{
    var compiled = current.Compile();
    var result = compiled.Invoke(instance);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Your output will be

> This is property 1
>
> This is property 2
>
> This is property 3
>
> This is property 4

Comment: Oh, it looks fine, and compiles, but... if only  in the following line

     var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, parameter);

the object was an actual property type, because now I get runtime error.

Comment: can you share your implementation of **WithProperty** method?

Comment: I updated the answer to set the parameter type to the type of the expression argument.

Comment: can you share your implementation of WithProperty method? Sorry - this is an external library, and I don't know it. What error are you exactly getting? The error I get is: System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.String'. It crashes when executing extractor = extractor.WithProperty(lambda)

Comment: So I think, the problem is with this line: var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TS, object>>(property, parameter); Instead of object, there should be a type of a correspoding property. I don't know how to make it dynamic - I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Please, can you at least, provide the definition for WithProperty method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182798/discussion-between-marcin-and-alfredo-a).

Answer (score 0):

`WithProperty` is a generic method that takes a type parameter implied by the result type of the property member access expression, which is what `TValue` represents in its declaration. Since you want to use reflection to generate the lambdas, you have to do the `WithProperty` call dynamically as well so you can call the one with the proper type (e.g. `WithProperty<String>` for a `String` property).

Here is an extension method that generates a lambda that consists of all the chained `WithProperty` calls for all the properties in a class, and then compiles and calls the lambda on the `IDataExtractor`. I chained all the calls together and then compiled because there might be some overhead for compiling, so I didn't want to compile and call code for each property individually.

```
public static class IDataExtractorExt {
    public static IDataExtractor<TRow> WithAllProperties<TRow>(this IDataExtractor<TRow> extractor) {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDataExtractor<TRow>), "p"); // final lambda parameter
        Expression ansBody = p; // start with p => p

        var withPropGenericMI = typeof(IDataExtractor<TRow>).GetMethod("WithProperty"); // lookup WithProperty<> generic method
        var properties = typeof(TRow).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties) {
            var withPropMI = withPropGenericMI.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType); // instantiate generic WithProperty<> to property type
            var pxp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRow), "x"); // property accessor lambda parameter
            var pxb = Expression.PropertyOrField(pxp, property.Name); // property accessor expression x.property
            Expression propExpr = Expression.Lambda(pxb, pxp); // x => x.property
            ansBody = Expression.Call(ansBody, withPropMI, propExpr); // build up p => p.WithProperty(x => x.property)...
        }

        return ((IDataExtractor<TRow>)(Expression.Lambda(ansBody, p).Compile().DynamicInvoke(extractor)));
    }
}
```