# How to populate point chart with with free separate lists?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `BindingLists` that store some objects I want to visualise on chart.

```
BindingList<Place> places;
BindingList<Person> people;
BindingList<Animal> animals;
```

All of them implement following interface:

```
interface IMapObject
    {
        int getPositionX();
        int getPositionY();
    }
```

How can I easily bind them all to single WinForms Point Chart? Every List need to be in separate `Series`. Chart should update automatically when I add new object to one of those lists.

Comment: What is Point Chart? Is that a native windows forms control?

Comment: @CodingYoshi it's System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart, native windows form control configured to display points in 2D space

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with the Chart control before but I understand how binding works so I am pretty sure this will will work.

First change your interface to this:

```
interface IMapObject
{
    int PositionX { get; set; }
    int PositionY { get; set; }
}
```

Implement that and then bind it like this:

```
ChartOne.Series.First().XValueMember = "PositionX";
ChartOne.Series.First().YValueMembers = "PositionY";

ChartOne.DataSource = places;
```

As you can see strings are used to indicate the `XValueMember` and the `YValueMembers`, and therefore does not really take advantage of your interface and do *Strongly Typed* binding. The question you need to ask is if the effort is really worth it or to just go with strings. If you want the strongly typed binding, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444294/strong-typed-windows-forms-databinding) thread for how it can be done (not directly related to charts but same idea). If I were you, I would just go with strings.

Comment: Your answer describes how to bind one BindingList to one Chart. What if I wanted to assign three BindingLists to Data Source?

Comment: @Piotrek would that not be a different series?

Comment: yes, each of those lists will be in different series. But in your answer you take only `places` as DataSource. Moreover, I can't find any way to bind List directy to Series instead of entire chart.

Comment: @Piotrek Not sure what you mean. For another series you would write `ChartOne.Series[1].XValueMember = "PositionX2"; ChartOne.Series[1].YValueMembers = "PositionY2"`. So your datasource will contain all the points for each series not just places.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean too ^^ `places` is only one of three sets of data which I need to display on single chart. I also need to display `people` and `animals` (and points representing them need to look differently)

Comment: Yes so you need have `places`, `people`, and `animals` in your datasource. Then do what i said in my previous comment.